# Create OneToOne field user object in Django serialization

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create the `User` object using my `Staff` class. My staff model looks like following,

```py
class Staff(models.Model):
    organization = models.ForeignKey(
        Organization, related_name='staff_organization', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

My serializer class is here,

```py
# create staff serializer
class StaffSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Staff
        fields = "__all__"

    def create(self, validated_data):
        username = validated_data.pop('username')
        email = validated_data.pop('email')
        password = validated_data.pop('password')
        user_instance, created = User.objects.get_or_create(
            username=username, email=email)

        if not created:
            user_instance.set_password(password)

        staff_instance = Staff.objects.create(
            **validate_data, user=user_instance)
        return staff_instance
```

Viewset class,

```py
class StaffViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = StaffSerializer
    queryset = Staff.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]


    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        staff = serializer.save(organization=self.request.user.staff.organization)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

I tried the post request as below,

```js
{"username":"tekson", "email":"tekson@gmail.com", "password":"admin"}
```

But it shows the error

```js
{
    "user": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}
```

I don't know how to create the user object from the staff. Please help me to figure out this error.

Comment: The Staff serializer expecting the 'user' and 'phone'  as keys in the input json. Also since your sending email and password to in the input you need to define serializer fields for these and include in fields section

Comment: Can you please help me to define serializer fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way could be, define a `UserSerializer`

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
```

Then edit your `StaffSerializer` to like this.

```
class StaffSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    user = UserSerializer(many=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Staff
        fields = "__all__"

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user_data = validated_data.pop('user')
        user_instance = User.objects.create(
            username=user_data['username'],email=user_data['email'], password=user_data['password'])
        user_instance.save()
        
        staff_instance = Staff.objects.create(
            **validated_data, user=user_instance)
        staff_instance.save()
        return staff_instance
```

Only downside to this approach is you will have to maintain nested relationship on the post data you send. So your data `{"username":"tekson", "email":"tekson@gmail.com", "password":"admin"}` will have to be changed to something like this.

```
{
    "phone": "",
    "user": {"username":"tekson", "email":"tekson@gmail.com", "password":"admin"}
}
```

Comment: It shows the same error, `user: this field is required`

Comment: You will have to change the format of data you are sending. Can you share your post data format here.

Comment: I don't know why, but it shows the `KeyError: 'password'`

Comment: Inside `create` method try to print `user_data` and check `password` field is there not.

Comment: Thank you very much. Finally, it works. This is the exact condition that I want

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to call `user_instance.save()` after `set_password()`.